# set row height of selected row

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I would like to change the row height of my selected row.
I tried this:

```
@IBAction func doubleClick(_ sender: NSTableView) {
   sender.rowHeight = 120.0
}
```

but the row height will stay the same.
what did I forget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reload the tableview data after changing the row height:

```
tableView.reloadData()
```